# Mapping a Qt base class signal to a slot in a derived class

Tags: c++, qt

I am having a problem with Qt signals and slots.  I am just learning Qt but I have lots of C++ experience.  I have derived a class from QTreeView and I want to handle the columnResized signal.  The slot is never being called and I am seeing this in the 'Application Output':

```
QObject::connect: No such signal TRecListingView::columnResized(int,int,int) in ../ec5/reclistingwidget.cpp:142
```

The class declaration looks like this:

```
class TRecListingView : public QTreeView
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    TRecListingView(QWidget *parent, TTopicPtr topic);
    ~TRecListingView();

private slots:
    void onColumnResized(int index, int oldsize, int newsize);

private:
    TRecListingModel *Model = 0;
};
```

In the constructor I am doing this:

```
connect(this,SIGNAL(columnResized(int,int,int)),
        this,SLOT(onColumnResized(int,int,int)));
```

I had this working earlier before I implemented the derived class.  Then I was mapping the signal to a slot in the parent widget.

I have tried running qmake and rebuilding the project.   I also tried this:

```
QTreeView *tv = this;
connect(tv,SIGNAL(columnResized(int,int,int)),
        this,SLOT(onColumnResized(int,int,int)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`columnResized`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreeview.html#columnResized) is not a signal, but slot, so you cannot connect to it.

Instead you can connect to the [`QHeaderView::sectionResized`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qheaderview.html#sectionResized)

```
connect(this->horizontalHeader(),SIGNAL(sectionResized(int,int,int)),
        this,                    SLOT(onColumnResized(int,int,int)));
```

Comment: QTableView has no horizontalHeader(), just a header(). So I got is working with this: connect(this->header(),SIGNAL(sectionResized(int,int,int)),
        this,          SLOT(onColumnResized(int,int,int)));

Answer (score 0):

Because it is not a signal:

From documentation:

```
void QTreeView::columnResized ( int column, int oldSize, int newSize ) [protected slot]
```

Try reimplement it:

```
#include <QTreeView>
#include <QHeaderView>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QDebug>


class TRecListingView : public QTreeView
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    TRecListingView(QWidget *parent=0):
        QTreeView(parent)

    {
        QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(fixHeader()));
    }


public slots:

    void fixHeader()
    {
        QHeaderView *hv = new QHeaderView(Qt::Horizontal, this);
        hv->setHighlightSections(true);
        this->setHeader(hv);
        hv->show();
    }
protected slots:
    void columnResized(int a, int b, int col)
    {
        qDebug() << "This is called";
    }

public slots:

};
```

Simple usage:

```
TRecListingView trec;

QStringList stringList;
stringList << "#hello" << "#quit" << "#bye";
QStringListModel *mdl = new QStringListModel(stringList);
trec.setModel(mdl);
trec.show();
```

Now it works properly and when you resize header, you'll see many `This is called` strings.

Comment: Actually you cannot override it, as its not virtual, but you can connect to the `QHeaderView::sectionResized` signal

Comment: @nicktook there is one way to change it. I totally rewrote my answer and now example works(I tested it on my computer). See it please.